# What is Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ around $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Consider $$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$$
I want to expand it over $z_0=0$ in a Laurent series.

We know that
$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
And I know that
$$\frac{1}{x-1}=-1-x-x^2-x^3-x^4-x^5+\cdots$$
But I can't get the correct answer for my desired series which is,
$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{12}-\frac{x^3}{720}+\frac{x^5}{30240}+O(x^6)$$
Any help?

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning in the 2 answers there. Shall I comment on it there?

Comment: Yes, please. Or add an explanation to your question what exactly you do not understand about these answers.

Comment: You can solve this if you have a Taylor series for $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z -1}=\sum a_n z^n$, so you should try finding this one first. Since $f(z)(e^z-1)=z$, then
$$\left(\sum_0^\infty a_n z^n\right)\left(\sum_0^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}\right) = 1$$

You can then use the Cauchy product rule to find a recursive definition for the coefficients $a_n$